# MySQL FULLTEXT Search not able to search string with large words

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a scenario where I need to search a particular string using FULLTEXT Search.

The string to search is:

```
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
```

The Query is

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME t1 WHERE (MATCH(t1.Name) AGAINST('rrr*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

Are there any limitations in MySQL FULLTEXT Search?

Comment: Why do you want to use fulltext search for this use case? A simple like comparison may work better and simpler. Fulltext search is there to search a normal text with words. Your sample does not have any words in it. The full value is just a random string and you seem to want to match the beginning of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mysql manual on [boolean fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) indicates, both minimum and maximum token size limits apply to such srarches:

> The minimum and maximum word length full-text parameters apply to FULLTEXT indexes created using the built-in FULLTEXT parser and MeCab parser plugin. innodb_ft_min_token_size and innodb_ft_max_token_size are used for InnoDB search indexes. ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len are used for MyISAM search indexes.

The default value of the max token size is 84.